# Stream already open - Exception

Tags: java, blackberry

```
private static void fileChunking() throws IOException {
    InputStream is = null;
    OutputStream os = null;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 102400;
    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    int responsecode = 0;
    String responsemessage = null;
    bufferSize = Math.min(content.length, maxBufferSize);
    buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
    bytesRead = is.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
    while (bytesRead > 0) {
        os.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        bytesAvailable = is.available();
        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        bytesRead = is.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
    }

    is.close();
    os.flush();
    responsecode = con.getResponseCode();
    responsemessage = con.getResponseMessage();
    System.out.print(responsemessage);

}
```

Code throws exception 'Stream already open' while reading 
  bytesRead = is.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

Comment: That code cannot execute, as you never set `is` to be non-null. What's the real code? NB you don't need that `Math.min()` thing: `read()` already behaves that way.

Comment: That code cannot compile because there is no variable with name `content` declared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You maybe already called `getReader()` elsewhere which is mutual exclusive with `getInputStream()`. Hard to say from this code, and that answer is a bit unlikely.

More likely you fetch the InputStream from a servlet field or some common variable, and two requests do reading.